# How do I make this regex URL pattern work in Django 2

Tags: regex, django, python-3.x, url-pattern, django-2.0

I need to make a URL pattern which could work with this URL:

```
mysite.com/blog/12/بلاگ-مثال
```

It contains utf-8 characters so I tried using `\X`:

```
re_path(r'^blog/?P<blog_id>[\d+]+/(?P<slug>[\X.*]+)/$', views.single_blog, name='single_blog')
```

But it didn't work. I don't know why. Maybe just because I'm not good in regex. So I tried a different pattern using just `.*` to accept anything:

```
re_path(r'^blog/?P<blog_id>[\d+]+/(?P<slug>[.*]+)/$', views.single_blog, name='single_blog')
```

But this also doesn't work and I get:

> The current path, blog/12/بلاگ-مثال, didn't match any of these.

So as I mentioned I'm not good in regex, what's the right way to fix this?

Is it the right time to say [now I have two problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems) or regex is the only way?

Comment: It didn't work because `\X` is not supported by Python `re` and `[.*]+` matches 1+ dots or asterisks, but not any chars. I guess you need `r'^blog/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$'`. If the `/` is optional, add `?` after it, `r'^blog/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/?$'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to match something did not work since `\X` is not supported by Python `re` and `[.*]+` matches 1+ dots or asterisks, but not any chars (because you put `.*` into `[...]` character class where they denote literal symbols, not special chars).

Besides, `[\d+]+` is also a character class matching any digit or `+`, 1 or more times, so there is also a problem.

You may use a `[^/]` negated character class to match any char but `/`:

```
r'^blog/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/?$'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of input
- `blog/` - a literal substrig
- `(?P<blog_id>\d+)` - Group "blog_id": 1+ digits
- `/` - a `/`
- `(?P<slug>[^/]+)` - Group "slug": 1+ chars other than `/`
- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string.

[Here is a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jdlPYj/1) (note highlighting characters from the Arabic script is not working there.)

Comment: FWIW when I put it into Google translate it detects Persian. I believe there's a difference between Persian and Arabic, but not sure how pertinent it is for this solution. They both use the same alphabet https://ru.lingualinx.com/blog/farsi-vs-arabic-a-look-at-how-the-two-languages-match-up/

Comment: @YvetteColomb Yes, they have common letters but doesn't share same alphabet. Besides, we can't conclude the language from a set of letters.

Comment: @
revo
 ah, sorry if I've offended you, I know little about the languages. Hm Im glad you edited, I was thinking of doing the same.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I wouldn't up-vote your comment if I felt offended.

Comment: I expect the answerer to rollback this edit but I hope it doesn't happen. @YvetteColomb

Comment: @YvetteColomb I haven't tried the answer yet. But the language is indeed Persian. Sure they share same alphabets except `گ پ ژ چ` which is used in my sample. So its definitely Persian. Just wanted to clear things up between you two before I test it. *giggles*

Comment: @AlexJolig Regex is language-unaware. It can only match *characters* that various languages may share. If my name is written as `Стрибижев`, I do not say it is composed of Russian chars, I'd say *Cyrillic*, because these are characters from the Cyrillic script. Here, the characters you have in the post are from the Arabic script, hence, I used "Arabic".

Answer (score 2):

> Is it the right time to say now I have two problems ...

In fact, you have chosen the right job for this task.

The other answer seems valid but can't tolerate to have the word *Persian* in it. I'm posting this answer to throw some points of why your own regex doesn't work as expected.

1. `?P<blog_id>[\d+]+`

Probably you meant a named group here, the same as the one you used later in regex. You missed opening and closing parentheses: `(?P<blog_id>[\d+]+)`. Also `[\d+]` means a character class consisted of digits and `+`. You need to remove `+`: `(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)`

2. `(?P<slug>[\X.*]+)`

Construction is fine as it should be but character class is not. `\X` doesn't have a special meaning in a character class, let alone Python that doesn't support it by its `re` module even. `.*` is no exception. In a character class almost all special tokens are treated literally.

So `[\X.*]` matches a `X` or a `.` or an asterisk `*`. You need to change it to something more general like `[^/]+` which means match up to the first slash (= match anything except forward slash).